# Comparing two CSV and writing the missing values(in different rows) to a file python

Tags: python

I need to compare two files and writing the missing values to another file

### File1.csv:

```
Monday, sports, swimming
Tuesday, study, running
Wednesday, jog, sprint
Thursday, nothing, Play
```

### File2.csv:

```
Monday
Wednesday
```

### output_File should be:

```
Tuesday, study, running
Thursday, nothing, Play
```

### What I have tried :

```
import csv

f1 = file('C:\File1.csv', 'rb')
f2 = file('C:File2.csv', 'rb')
f3 = file('C:\output_file.csv', 'wb')
c1 = csv.reader(f1)
c2 = csv.reader(f2)
c3 = csv.writer(f3)
masterlist = [row for row in c2]
for hosts_row in c1:
    for master_row in masterlist:
        results_row = hosts_row
        if hosts_row[0] == master_row[0]:
                print results_row
                c3.writerow(results_row)
```

### Output_file.csv:

```
Monday, sports, swimming
Wednesday, jog, sprint
```

Comment: You're doing the exact opposite of the task; why check `if hosts_row[0] == master_row[0]:`?! Perhaps you should look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

f1 = file('C:\File1.csv', 'rb')
f2 = file('C:File2.csv', 'rb')
f3 = file('C:\output_file.csv', 'wb')
c1 = csv.reader(f1)
c2 = csv.reader(f2)
c3 = csv.writer(f3)
masterlist = [row[0] for row in c2]

for hosts_row in c1:
    if hosts_row[0] not in masterlist:
        print hosts_row
        c3.writerow(hosts_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter and without `cvs` (you actually don't need it):

```py
file1 = [line.strip() for line in open('File1.csv')]
file2 = [line.strip() for line in open('File2.csv')]

with open('output_File.cvs', 'w') as f:
    for line in file1:
        if not line.split(',')[0] in file2:
            f.write(line + '\n')
```

---

**Edit:** The one-line lovers among you can replace the loop with

```
f.writelines('\n'.join(filter(lambda l: not l.split(',')[0] in file2, file1)))
```